# How can I use input data in main activity after "okay" in alertDialog

Tags: android

I am having trouble in getting input from dialog. (I am very very newbie in android studio.) After some research, I followed some instruction. then I got problem.

```
public class BuyDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
public interface BuyDialogListener{
    void onInputData(String input);
}

private BuyDialogListener call;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        call = (BuyDialogListener) activity;
    } catch(ClassCastException e) {
        Log.d("test", "activity doesnt implement");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buy_dialog, null);
    final EditText input = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.buy_input);
    builder.setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton("confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     String inputStr = input.getText().toString();
                     dismiss();
                     call.onInputData(inputStr);
                }
            });


    return builder.create();
}
```

}

In mainActivity, I got this and

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
            if(IsAble(goods)){
                openBuy();
                Log.d("test", inputEdit.getText().toString());
    });    

public void onInputData(String input) {
        Toast.makeText(this, input+" items is purchased", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        inputStr = input (//inputStr is global variable in this activity)
    }
```

Toast works fine with input data but it seems that "inputStr" outside of onInputData method doesn't change at all. and it will make my program crush down. How can I use input data in mainActivity. Thanks!

Comment: "it seems that "inputStr" outside of onInputData method doesn't change at all." Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: Does your activity implements `BuyDialogListener`?

Comment: @Tommy in MainActiviy, I declare inputStr in order to copy input value in onInputData . then I thought that input value will be assigned into inputStr then I can use that value in other method. however, the inputStr value doesn't change at all.
 public void onInputData(String input) {
        Toast.makeText(this, input+" items is purchased", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        inputStr = input (//inputStr is global variable in this activity)
    }

After entering input in dialog, it shows toast with msg. then If I use "println(inputStr) in other method in mainActivity, it doesn't change.

Comment: @РасулA-ев yes, mainActivity implements BuyDialog.BuyDialogListener

Comment: Where and when do u call the other method? Make sure u call it after user input and dismiss dialog.